# Best way to work with store hours in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, struct

I'm building an app in Swift that will take in a store's hours from Firebase and want to represent it in my code as something like "monday.close"  to get 02:30. What's the best way to do something like this? Pic below is what the data looks like in Firebase.

[image: Firebase Data]

```
init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    //initialize food item here
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.address = dictionary["address"] as? String ?? ""
    self.restaurantLogo = UIImage(named: "")
    self.menuItems = dictionary["menuItems"] as? [Food] ?? []
    self.deliverUberEats = dictionary["uberEatsLink"] as? String ?? ""
    self.deliverDoorDash = dictionary["doordashLink"] as? String ?? ""
    self.deliverGrubhub = dictionary["grubhubLink"] as? String ?? ""
    self.restaurantID = ""
    self.priceRange = dictionary["price"] as? Int ?? 0
    self.hoursOpen = dictionary["hours"] as? [String : [String: String]]
}

struct RestaurantHours {
    var MonOpen: Date?
    var MonClose: Date?
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific, please? This could be a simple task for a `Struct` if you have limited needs, or a Core Data entity, if you need to persistently handle many stores. What do you want to achieve, what have you tried so far, how does your code look like right now (in very simple terms)?

Comment: I updated my original question with the current code. Instead of MonClose, I'd like to do Monday.close. Right now these are in a struct called Restaurant. in its current state, MonOpen and MonClose don't have any data since I'm having a hard time extracting the specific fields I need. Should this just be a struct in a struct in a struct essentially?

Comment: To add, I am just looking to have it for limited needs. Not saving it to core data or anything crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already have a dictionary to store the Firebase opening hours, called `hoursOpen`.

Instead of using a notation like "monday.open", one option you have is to keep that dictionary as your source of data and retrieve the hours using a function, like this:

```
    func restaurantHours(day: String, when: String) -> String {
        let safeWhen = hoursOpen[day.lowercased()] ?? ["open": "closed"]
        let safeTime = safeWhen[when.lowercased()] ?? "closed"
        return safeTime
    }
```

Here's how you use it (*but correct Firebase or parse your data to keep all weekdays lowercased!*):

```
Text(restaurantHours(day: "Monday", when: "open"))    // 02.30
Text(restaurantHours(day: "MondAy", when: "close"))   // 22.00
Text(restaurantHours(day: "Tuesday", when: "open"))   // 02.30
Text(restaurantHours(day: "frIDAy", when: "clOSe"))   // closed
```